# Asp.Net Custom Errors Default Redirect not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, web-config, custom-error-pages

In my web.config file I added a default error redirect page,

However I get this error,

"Description: An exception occurred while processing your request. Additionally, another exception occurred while executing the custom error page for the first exception. The request has been terminated."

I tried all suggestions found on internet and did not help me.

My project: MVC 5, Angular 5, Visual studio 2017.

Thank you.

Comment: Try turning off your default custom error page temporarily. If you encounter any exception shown after page load, include them in your question.

Comment: I already know the error and want to test redirection to error page. In fact I forced this error to happen to test custom errors configuration.